# How to split a text file in python using the amount of words per line without using modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I'm writing this script where a text file is to be split into lists based on the amount of words per line, I need to generate a dictionary but no need to worry about it; I'm having trouble trying to split this text:

So let's say that I have:

```
word1:
word word

more words
word2:
another word
word3:
word4:
```

and I want:

```
[[[word:], [word word], [more words]],[[word2:], [another word]], 
[[word3:]], [[word4:]]]
```

This is the code:

```
from typing import List, Dict, TextIO, Tuple
def read_file(TextIO) -> Dict[str, List[tuple]]:

text = open('text_file.txt', 'r')
data = []
indexes = []

for line in text.readlines():
    l =  line.strip().split(',')
    data.append(l)
    for lists in data:
        if lists == ['']:
            data.remove(lists)

for elements in data:
    if len(elements) == 1:
        if ':' in elements[0][-1]:
            indexes.append(data.index(elements))
```

How can I use the indexes to cut the data in the parts that I need? or how else could I cut the text file in the parts that I need without using modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a series of operations that do not make sense – possibly they were leftovers from earlier attempts. You don't have any data with comma's in them, so `.split(',')` is obsolete. I also do not see what appending to `indexes` ought to be doing.

Instead, take the following approach: append words that end with `:` as a new list; append all other phrases *to* that last list. The only deviation from this is that blank line; it seems this should be discarded, else it will add a `''` to one of the lists.

Thus, all that is necessary is this short code:

```
data = []

with open('text.txt', 'r') as text:
    for line in text:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            if line.endswith(':'):
                data.append([line])
            else:
                data[-1].append(line)

print (data)
```

Output as per requirement:

```
[['word1:', 'word word', 'more words'], ['word2:', 'another word'], ['word3:'], ['word4:']]
```

Comment: There is no reason for `text.readlines()` in the loop. Just do `for line in text:` since files are iterable.